# Pagina web no segura pese a que tengo certificado SSL

Tags: laravel, ssl, certificado

Esta ocurriendo esto, en el sitio esta instalado el certificado SSL y aparece como seguro, pero si entras especificamente escribiendo www.car-e.mx aparece como no seguro (Cosa que no ocurre si entras escribiendo solamente car-e.mx, en ese caso si marca el sitio web como seguro)

Estuve investigando, y una de las cosas que consegui es que podrian ser algunas imagenes e iconos que esten ocacionando este problema, cuando hago clic en mas informacion en el cartel de pagina web no segura, me aparecen este listado de imagenes/iconos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El punto es que el proyecto esta desarrollado en Laravel y no se como corregir esto, espero puedan ayudarme, y muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Cuando entras desde http://car-e.mx redirecciona a la pagina segura https://www.car-e.mx, pero cuando lo haces con http://www.car-e.mx no lo hace. Tendrias que ver como redireccionar de http a https en el servidor que instalaste Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema de redirección, no estás obligando a entrar a tus visitantes por el protocolo `https://` crea o edita tu archivo `.htaccess` y agrega las liguientes líneas:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Con esto haces que las personas que entren por `http://` las redireccione si o si a `https://`

Comment: Luego de hacer esto, hace falta limpiar los caches o algo? Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: con un ctrl+F5 bastará amigo

Comment: Ya logre solucionarlo! al final el fragmento de codigo que me diste ya estaba puesto por el desarrollador anterior en el archivo .htaccesss, entonces no era eso, pero gracias a tu respuesta supe guiarme un poco mejor y logre crear un middleware para forzar las redireccion al dominio seguro, si alguien alguna vez le pasa esto y llega esta pregunta [https://www.legendblogs.com/how-to-force-redirect-http-to-https-in-laravel-7x-and-6x-and-more] aqui fue donde consegui la solucion!

Comment: Me alegra que lo solucionaras, pero tu enlace está roto